Plant texture turning black in the transparent part
I created these plans using an image as a base, with two planes to form each plan. In the viewport, they appear correctly, with the black part of the image invisible. However, in the render, this black part is showing. I managed to resolve this by increasing the Transparent Max Bounces value to 45 (it was at 8). The problem is that this made rendering much heavier and, on the first rendering attempt, Blender crashed.




Here is the material of the object.

